# Vertically Centering various content in a fixed inline block

Tags: html, centering, css

I have an issue that I just can't figure out and need some help from this wonderful community.  I am trying to figure out how to center elements within a div, both vertically and horizontally.  Seems simple enough but everything I can find just doesn't seem to work.  Here are the criteria:

First, the page has a fixed header.  The body is fixed as well, starting below the header and overflow is set to auto so it can scroll if need be.  In the body, I have div containers that are wrapped in  so the entire div is a clickable link (basically a big button).  The reason I am using divs instead of a table is because I need it to be completely responsive and self centering.  The divs are set as inline-blocks so they will center themselves and come one after another.  The divs also have a fixed height and width, but the body does not so it can remain responsive.

It took me some work to get to this point, and I finally got it after trying different methods, but now I can't get the last item: centering the content in the individual div containers.  In each container I have an image and some text.  Each box might vary in image size and amount of text.  I need to vertically align the image and text within the div, as well as retain horizontal alignment.

Here is my fiddle showing where I am at now: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dave_K/150u7x0d/1/)

I tried wrapping the content within the box divs and applied centering to that, but it doesn't work when the parent div is an inline block.  I can get it to center with that div wrapper set as a block, but then the parent divs get all wonky and don't line up right.  Any advice here would be great.

Here is the Code:

```css
#t_header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#t_body {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.t_box {
    width: 170px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #000000;
}
.t_box_centerer {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="t_header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="t_body"> 
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <div class="t_box_centerer">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br>
                    This is my 1st image
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <div class="t_box_centerer">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br>
                    This is my 2nd image.  This has more text than the first but the next has less.
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
     <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <div class="t_box_centerer">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br>
                    This is my 3rd image.  There is less text.
            </div>
        </div>
     </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Update the css class hope this will fix as i understand you want to center contents with in t_body?

```css
#t_body {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That centers the whole works in jsfiddle, I will update my jsfiddle.  I must already have some centering in my actual page that kept those elements centered, what I am after here is to vertically and horizontally center the content in the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and cleaned up your HTML a bit, which meant using less for more for good practice.

I also dug into your CSS markup after a bit of cleanup and figured that all you needed to do was add 'margin: 0 auto' property to a desired element, in order to make sure they are always centered within their container. Note that the 'display: table-cell' was moved to your custom body container. Let me know if you have more questions.

```css
#t_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#t_body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#t_body a {
    width: 170px;
    height: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #000000;
}
.t_box {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.t_box img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="t_header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="t_body">
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif"/><br/>
            This is my 1st image
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif"/><br/>
            This is my 2nd image.  This has more text than the first but the next has less.
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif"/><br>
            This is my 3rd image.  There is less text.
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I am an amateur, so forgive my messy code.  Unfortunately, your changes remove all the key elements of this page.  First, I need the header to be fixed and the body to scroll.  In my actual page I have about 20 of these boxes and they need to be fully responsive so they lay out properly on tablets and phones as well as desktops.  Your design above makes the boxes static and unresponsive (via the display:table-cell).  This is why I used display:inline-block.  Also your code above removes margins on the boxes.

Comment: Finally, while your solution does center the contents horizontally, it doesn't center them vertically, which is my main issue (updated the title of my post to reflect this).  And the margin 0 auto doesn't seem to work with inline-blocks.  :(

Comment: My pleasure, when you answered I was at lunch so I couldn't code; but I had a feeling that if you took the time to work around the issue using the ideas I threw on the snippet, that it would lead you to your answer... glad it was so :) feel free to upvote, add me as the answer or to add your own

Answer (score 0):

OK, AGE's answer helped me figure it out.  I am not sure what the etiquette here is, if I should post my own answer instead of editing the question.  I can delete if it isn't the right way to do answer this.

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dave_K/150u7x0d/5/)

I started by removing the centering div, then made the  element in the body div an inline block (per ACE's answer above).  I still had to set the height and width in the box div, but since that div was not an inline element, the vertical-align: middle worked on it.

Now it has the fixed header and scrollable body, the boxes are the same size and are lined up, the content is centered both horizontally and vertically, and the boxes are centered on the page and responsive to the browser size.  That hits all my needs, and I will see if I can successfully apply these changes to my web page.  Thanks for the help, sometimes it just takes a different approach to get the results!

Here is the code:

```css
#t_header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#t_body {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#t_body a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
.t_box {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 170px;
    height: 250px;  
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="t_header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="t_body"> 
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br/>
                    This is my 1st image.
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br/>
                    This is my 2nd image.  This has more text than the first but the next has less.
        </div>
    </a>
     <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="t_box">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/E8MzWW2.gif" width="100%"/><br/>
                    This is my 3rd image.  There is less text.
        </div>
     </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: 'Answer your question' is what you're looking for, do a search on this webpage for it. Also you can up vote the people who helped you reach the answer by clicking on the up arrow next to their comment/answer. If their answer is correct you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark next to their answer.